# Spark: Removing rows which occur less than N times

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Lets say that I am having the following rdd:

```py
a = [('a',1),('a',2),('a',3),('b',1),('b',4),('c',3)]
anRDD = sc.parallelize(a)
```

And I want to get the rows that they key occurs more than N times(for this example lets say more or equal than 2). And in another rdd the ones that where excluded.

What I do is the following:

```py
threshold = 2
anRDD.persist()
grouped_counts = anRDD
                    .toDF(['letter','number'])
                    .groupBy('letter')
                    .count()

downFromLimit = grouped_counts.filter(grouped_counts['count']<threshold).select("letter").map(lambda x:x.letter).collect()  
upTheLimit = grouped_counts.filter(grouped_counts['count']>=threshold).select("letter").map(lambda x:x.letter).collect()

upData = anRDD.filter(lambda x:x[0] in upTheLimit)
downData = anRDD.filter(lambda x:x[0] in downFromLimit)
anRDD.unpersist()
```

It does what I want but it should something more clear,easier and more efficient than this.

If I use `reduceByKey` and count the length of the values would it be more beneficial?

Any other idea?

Answer (score 7):

Both your approach and Alberto's are pulling all the keys back to the driver which will be a problem if you have a lot of them.

Instead of doing that I would create the aggregated DF and then join that against the original data.  Then you can use partitioning on write to save out both groups in one pass.

You should keep all your data in DataFrames whenever possible instead of RDD.  There are a large number of optimizations when using DataFrames which is especially applicable when using pyspark.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F    

df = anRDD.toDF(['letter','number'])

counts = df.groupBy('letter') \
           .count()

# Join to the original data
df = df.join(counts, df.letter == counts.letter)

# Add the column to partition on
updated = df.withColumn('group', F.when(df.count < 2, 'down').otherwise('up')) \
           .select('letter', 'group')

# Partitioning lets us write out both groups at once, instead of recomputing stages
updated.write.partitionBy('group').text('/some/output/path')
```

This will create a folder structure for you like this:

```
/some/output/path
     group=down
          part-0000
          ...
     group=up
          part-0000
          ...
```

Comment: and if i dont want to write them and just create 2 new dataframes, the best way to do it is to make 2 filters?

Comment: Yeah.  I don't know of any other way to divide up data.  I have found on EMR/S3 though it is sometimes faster to just write out the data partitioned and read it back in.  You end up adding some IO work, but you don't have recompute stages for each resulting filtered RDD.  It depends on how much work you are doing before after though.

Comment: but counting should mean less keys, so would it be that bad returning these to driver?

Comment: It depends on how many distinct key values there are.  If there are 10 it would be fine, if there are 10 million it would have issues.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [countByKey](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=rdd#pyspark.RDD.countByKey) if the number of keys isn't too big. Also, the result could be converted to a [Broadcast](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=rdd#pyspark.Broadcast) and finally filter the [RDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=rdd#pyspark.RDD).

```py
rdd = sc.parallelize([('a',1),('a',2),('a',3),('b',1),('b',4),('c',3)])

broadcast = sc.broadcast(rdd.countByKey())
broadcast.value
# defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'a': 3, 'c': 1, 'b': 2})

rdd.filter(lambda x: broadcast.value[x[0]] >= 2).take(10) 
# [('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 3), ('b', 1), ('b', 4)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not sure which of the two methods is more efficient (yours and the one that I gave). The number of keys is huge in my case and using broadcast could affect negatively.

Answer (score 0):

Doing the same thing in Scala

```
// assuming df is a dataframe that already exists

val count_df = df.select($"column_name").groupBy($"column_name").count()
val join_df = df.join(count_df, df.col("column_name") === count_df.col("column_name"))
val new_df = join_df.filter($"count" >= 2)
```